# Windows shell scripting string search and replace with variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following script:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set LOCAL_DIR=C:\wamp\www

set CLASS_NAME=%5
set TEST_NAME=%7

set CLASS_PATH=%6
set TEST_PATH=%8
set BOOT_PATH=%4

set CLASS_PATH=%CLASS_PATH:C:\wamp\www=/var/www%
set TEST_PATH=%TEST_PATH:C:\wamp\www=/var/www%
set BOOT_PATH=%BOOT_PATH:C:\wamp\www=/var/www%

echo phpunit-skelgen %1 %2 --bootstrap='%BOOT_PATH'

:C:\wamp\www\plink -batch -ssh -pw @dmin205 root@192.168.1.90 phpunit-skelgen %1 %2 --bootstrap=%BOOT_PATH '%CLASS_NAME' '%CLASS_PATH' '%TEST_CLASS' '%TEST_PATH'"
```

I am trying to make the "C:\wamp\www" and "/var/www" variables but when I do the thing stops working...anyone have any ideas?

I was hoping to even go as far and programmatically figure out where these paths were and save them in environment for the life time of Windows session

EDIT | The %BOOT_PATH will not render in the final echo'ed output...

Comment: the problem is with `:` but it's easy for fix

Comment: Which : -- I kinda need the one for C:\ -- whats the fix?

Comment: writtinig...Just give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "LOCAL_DIR=C:\wamp\www"

set "CLASS_NAME=%~5"
set "TEST_NAME=%~7"

set "CLASS_PATH=%~6"
set "TEST_PATH=%~8"
set "BOOT_PATH=%~4"



for  %%# in ( "CLASS_PATH" "TEST_PATH" "BOOT_PATH" ) do (
    for %%z in ("!%%~#!") do set "_path=%%~pnz\"
    set "%%~#=!_path:\=/!
) 

echo %CLASS_PATH%--%TEST_PATH%--%BOOT_PATH%
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Check this.As I understand you want to remove drive letter and replace slashes with backslashes.

Comment: This is response is interesting but doesn't quite solve my problem...I need to change C:\wamp/www to /var/wwww and convert forward slashes back to back slashes...